# APK update on Google Play doesn't trigger update on Android device?

Tags: android, google-play, updates

More than one week ago I deployed version 1.0 of my apk on Google Play - no problems. On January 6th, I deployed version 1.1. After Google Play had updated the apk for public, I got the update trigger both on my Android tab and on my smartphone. Unfortunately there was a bug in the last version, so I updated again to version 1.1.1 on Janurary 7th and deployed it on Google Play. It's already provided to public. This usually takes about 1 - 2 hours. If one downloads the app, he gets version 1.1.1. I already tested that. But since the latest update, both my smartphone and my tab doesn't get the update trigger anymore. So they don't know that there is an update again. The deployment was 12 hours ago, so there must be the trigger by now. With the update on version 1.1, I didn't have problems and I got the trigger as soon as Google Play updated the apk for public.

Any ideas why the update trigger doesn't work and both Android 3.1 tablet and on Android 2.1 smartphone? I guess it's a Google Play or apk issue since it doesn't work on both devices.

(The version name and number in AndroidManifest have been incremented. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to update the apk on Google Play)

What I noticed: Google Play haven't updated the statistics for my app since Jan. 6th although it should update daily (and it worked until 2 days ago). Maybe it's based on the same issue.

Comment: may be it happens because you have tested the app on your smart phones. so it is updated.

Comment: The app on the phone is not up-to-date. It's the previous version.

Comment: Were you using the old or new dashboard?

Comment: dont mind.from where you have put the apk in phone?

Comment: @Carl I used the new CMS of Google Play.

Comment: means it will trigger when the version code is different that is the android market version code and your installed apk's version code

Comment: @Pankaj I already said that I incremented the numbers. Otherwise you can't upload on Google Play.

Comment: As an experiment, you might try performing a new APK update using the old dashboard.

Comment: @Carl Nice tip. By the way, it seems that this doesn't affect the most people because the most ppl knew about the update and already downloaded it. I guess this means it is no Google Play issue. Rather an Android issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what's going on, but I can't definitely say if this is really so. Google changed something in Google Play (like recently the concept of some implementation issues like Google Play Services instead of MapView), so I think that Android versions beyond Android 2.2 and above are already too old for the last changes (They cannot even use Google Play Services). Maybe that's the reason why it doesn't work. On my Android 3.1 tablet it obviously works again. At this one time as it didn't work, there was maybe a bug in Google Play.

It this is wrong, plz correct me.